# PHP diff array value and not key diff

Tags: php, arrays

I have a problem and I hope, I can be helped to fix this problem.

My problem is I got this two arrays

```
$array1 = ["test1" => "red", "test2" => "blue", "test3" => "green"];
$array2 = ["test1" => "red", "test2" => "blue", "test3" => "blue"];
```

as you can see the difference is the array key test3's value there are a diff, my problem is i need to know the key test3 have a diff and from $array1 to $array2

I have tried `array_diff` and `array_intersect` but its not what I want. 
I have a product and i need to know what there are changes from last run, and if i use on of this to command its not telling my where the diff are but what the diff is.

Can somebody help here and explain what i can do or about there are a function to handle this problem?

Comment: What abaout [array_diff_assoc()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php)

Comment: Or `array_intersect_key`

Comment: Thanks Mark, can you pls make its a awser, the only one function i not have trying haha.

Comment: array_diff works my frriend

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $array1 = array("a" => "green", "b" => "brown", "c" => "blue", "d" => "red");
    $array2 = array("a" => "green", "b" => "brown", "c" => "blue", "d" => "yellow");
    $result = array_diff_assoc($array1, $array2);
    echo print_r($result, true);
?>
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$array1 = ["test1" => "red", "test2" => "blue", "test3" => "green"];
$array2 = ["test1" => "red", "test2" => "blue", "test3" => "blue"];

$result=array_diff($array1,$array2);
print_r($result);
?>

This shud work
o/p : Array ( [test3] => green )
```